# Как сделать чтобы бот на telebot отправлял курс биткоина?

Tags: python, telebot

Как сделать чтобы в боте выводилось примерное сообщение  `Курс BTC - 47138.45 $ Это ~ 3488645.63 ₽` ?

Answer (score -1):

Можно найти возможное API для получения курса биткоина, их довольно много.
Один из таких сервисов есть https://www.coingecko.com/ru/api, довольно неплохой сервис и дает большой выбор криптовалют.

У меня есть уже готовый такой бот, делал для себя, вот функция в которой я выдавал сумму криптовалюты, там можно получать очень много информации о криптовалюте которая вам интересна. Я просил пользователя ввести название криптовалюты и ожидал сообщения:

```
bot.register_next_step_handler(name_crypt, self.get_currency_cryptomoney, old_message=name_crypt)
```

Ниже сам код функции который я использовал

```
def get_currency_cryptomoney(self, message, old_message):
        global crypt
        crypt = {'id': 0, 'name': None, 'prices': None, 'id_name': None, 'find': False}
        for i in range(len(json_crypto_list)):
            if json_crypto_list[i]['id'].lower() == message.text.lower() or json_crypto_list[i]['symbol'].lower() == message.text.lower() or json_crypto_list[i]['name'].lower() == message.text.lower():
                crypt['find'] = True
                crypt['id'] = str(i)
                crypt['id_name'] = str(json_crypto_list[i]['id'])
                crypt['name'] = str(json_crypto_list[i]['name'])
                crypt['prices'] = requests.get(f"https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/{crypt['id_name']}").json()['market_data']['current_price']
        self.keyboard9 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        self.read_conditions = types.InlineKeyboardButton(' Вернуться', callback_data="get_name_crypt")
        self.keyboard9.add(self.read_conditions)
        if crypt['find'] == True:
            bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.id)
            bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=message.chat.id, message_id=old_message.id, text=f" Цена криптовалюты {crypt['name']} (ID: {crypt['id']}):\n\nRUB: {str(crypt['prices']['rub'])} ₽\nUSD: {str(crypt['prices']['usd'])} $\nEUR: {str(crypt['prices']['eur'])} €\n\n Все актуальные курсы берутся с сайта coingecko.com", parse_mode='Markdown')
        else:
            bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.id)
            bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=message.chat.id, message_id=old_message.id,text=f"⛔️ Криптовалюты {message.text} не существует.", parse_mode='Markdown')
```

Тот самый бот который я делал https://t.me/cryptocurrency_price_RUS_bot